# How to feed results of SQL statement into a GridView, not the SQL statement itself?

Tags: vb.net

This has got to be close, but it's been a long day and I'm tired now so I can;t really see what the problem is.  Basically, I have a table in SQL Server with 2 columns; one has the names of reports and the other has some SQL Scripts that I want to pass into a GridView, based on what a user selects from a ListBox.  Here is my code.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try

            Dim sqlConn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=EXCEL-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True")
            sqlConn.Open()
            Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("Select ReportName From [Table_1] order by ReportName", sqlConn)
            Dim dsColumns As New DataSet
            Dim daAdapter As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

            daAdapter.Fill(dsColumns)
            If dsColumns.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
                ListBox1.Items.Clear()
                For i As Integer = 0 To dsColumns.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
                    ListBox1.Items.Add(dsColumns.Tables(0).Rows(i)(0).ToString())
                Next
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim connetionString As String
        Dim SqlStr As String
        Dim connection As SqlConnection
        Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim myItem As String

        connetionString = "Data Source=EXCEL-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True"
        connection = New SqlConnection(connetionString)
        'Dim iIndex As Integer = ListBox1.SelectedIndex
        myItem = ListBox1.SelectedItem
        SqlStr = "select SqlScript from [Table_1] Where ReportName = '" & myItem & "'"
        Try
            connection.Open()
            adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(SqlStr, connection)
            adapter.Fill(ds)
            connection.Close()
            DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try

    End Sub

End Class
```

I guess the problem is passing the SQL to the GridView.  When I select the first Item, I see this in my GridView.

```
SELECT [OrderID]
      ,[CustomerID]
      ,[EmployeeID]
      ,[OrderDate]
      ,[RequiredDate]
      ,[ShippedDate]
      ,[ShipVia]
      ,[Freight]
      ,[ShipName]
      ,[ShipAddress]
      ,[ShipCity]
      ,[ShipRegion]
      ,[ShipPostalCode]
      ,[ShipCountry]
  FROM [Test].[dbo].[Orders]
```

That's pretty close, but I want to get that SQL fed into the GridView, and get the results of the SQL displayed in the GridView, not eh SQL statement itself.

This is what I see now.
[image]

I want to see something more like this.
[image]

Finally, I am curious to know of the GridView can be made dynamic, so if I stretch out the window the GridView shows more columns.  Now, if I stretch out the form window, the GridView stays static.

Comment: You never call the actual **SqlDataReader** please take a look at the msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fksx3b4f.aspx

Comment: Use the `.Anchor` property of the `DataGridView` to make it resize with the form

Comment: You need to actually run the Sql statement with a new, different DataAdapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually run the retrieved Sql statement:

```
sqlstr = "select SqlScript from [Table_1] Where ReportName = '" & myItem & "'"
Try
  connection.Open()
  Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sqlstr, connection)
  Dim sqlstr_report As String = CStr(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
  cmd.Dispose()
  adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlstr_report, connection)
  adapter.Fill(ds)
  connection.Close()
  DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
```

Use the `.Anchor` property of the `DataGridView` to make it resize with the form